# Find a mobius transformation that maps the open unit disc to the upper half plane with T(0) = 1+2i

Tags: complex-analysis

I know how to find one that maps the open unit disc to the upper half plane, but the extra condition is throwing me off. Can someone help?

Comment: You can map from the disk to the upper half plane and then map the upper half plane to itself to get the point condition. By scaling you can move $i$ vertically, and then you can horizontally shift.

Comment: How? Would a map from the upper half plane to itself have to take the real line to the real line? (boundary to boundary)

Comment: real coefficients $ \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$  with $ad-bc > 0$

Comment: yep, scaling and horizontal shifts do this

Comment: I still don't see how to do it. How can you send 0 to 1+2i with only real coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the transformation (which you stated that you have) that sends the unit disk and $0$, to the upper half plane and (presumably) $i$.

Next apply the scaling transformation to send $i$ to $2i$.

Finally horizontally translate to sent $2i$ to $1+2i$.

These last two transformations are also Möbius transformations which send the upper half plane to itself.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank ya. Sorry for being difficult.

Comment: Not at all! Glad it made sense